# Execute selection and redirect output to new buffer/tab

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, external-command

I want to automate something I started using.

Short story is I have a file with some lines and I want to execute each line every now and then and see its' output, but I don't want it to override the contents of the buffer containing the commands. Instead, I rather store it in a new buffer/tab so that when I close everything nothing is stored.

I did something with mktemp, but I want to use vim's internal capabilities.

My workflow is currently as follows:

- select the command I want to execute (example: `ping 8.8.8.8`)
- execute `:tabnew | r! <YANKED TEXT>` where I get `<YANKED TEXT>` from using `ctrl+r`

Output is stored in a new tab, but I want to automate it, preferably using `vmap <somekey>` somehow to be able to press a key to evaluate a command and see its' output in a new buffer/tab.

I don't know how to mimic what I currently do to a `vmap` binding. I tried `vmap <F2> tabnew | r! @"` which failed (probably for some obvious reason).

Nice to have:

- I don't want to use plugins for this, seems simple enough to accomplish.
- I don't want to write complex vimscripts.
- I want to understand each step.

Pointers to what to read to accomplish this would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

You can achieve this with the following mapping:

```
vmap <F2> y:tabnew<CR>:r! <C-R>"<CR>
```

This simply mimics the keystrokes that you were previously entering manually, including the presses of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key: `<CR>`. (You should note therefore that, like your manual steps, this has the side-effect of setting the yank and unnamed registers to the yanked text.)

#### Why Your Command Didn't Work

Your command was failing for a couple of reasons:

1. The bar character `|` in your command is interpreted as ending the mapping, so the following `r! @"` is then run immediately as a separate command. An alternative solution is to use the `<Bar>` stand in:

   ```
   vnoremap <F2> y:tabnew <Bar> r! <C-R>"<CR>
   ```

   This will create a mapping that actually uses a `|` in the ex command that is run. (If the difference is unclear, try removing the final `<CR>` from the end of the mapping and then invoke it.)
2. You can't use `@` in that context. It doesn't expand into the contents of the register: instead the entire `@"` is passed to the shell as the command to run.

#### Suggestion: Use `nore`

As a side-note, it's generally better to use the non-recursive forms of the various map commands:

```
vnoremap <F2> y:tabnew<CR>:r! ^R"<CR>
```

You should only use the plain forms if you have a specific reason for doing so (which will be almost never.)

#### Further Reading

The part of the documentation that explains all of the above is Chapter 40 of the user manual:

```
:help usr_40
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I wonder what the `<CR>`s are for...

Comment: @ReutSharabani See my edit: this method mimics *all* the keystrokes you would enter manually.

Comment: @ReutSharabani And see my latest edit for a different method and a reading suggestion.

Comment: cool, I am usually skeptics about dev-made-docs (unlike user-made-docs) but this seems very useful. Explains some of the corners as well...

Comment: I've actually improved to `noremap y$:tabnew<CR>:r! ^R"<CR>` so I don't even have to select the command (won't work for multiline, but ok for now...)

Comment: @ReutSharabani Prepend a `^` motion too, and it'll work regardless of current cursor position within the line: `nnoremap <F2> ^y$:tabnew<CR>:r! ^R"<CR>`

Comment: Few things: 1) You may want to use key-notation instead of `^R`. 2) Use `xnoremap` instead of `vnoremp` as you probably only want this to work in visual mode and not select mode as well. e.g. `xnoremap <F2> y:tabnew<CR>:r! <C-R>"<CR>`. 3) Might also want to mention this has the side-effect of mutating the unnamed register which can be a bit of a surprise to some folks

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks. 1 & 3 are good points: I'll update my answer. I thought about 2 when writing the post, and respectfully disagree.